# How to count md5sum of executed command in bash

Tags: bash, hash, md5sum

I have a wrapper script for compiling command to count md5sum of executed command and time it (also some ither stuff). Point is I have to calculate md5sum inside wrapper script.

problem is that m5sum return same output for `gcc main.c` and `gcc "main.c"` but command is different.

Here is simple code.

```
$ cat sc.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cmd="$@"
cmdh=$(echo "$cmd" | md5sum - | cut -f1 -d" ")

echo "CMD ${cmd}"
echo "MD5 ${cmdh}"

time $@
```

Here is one output:

```
$ ./sc.sh gcc -c main.c -o out
CMD gcc -c main.c -o out
MD5 b671a0f3b1235aa91e5f86011449c698

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Here is second. I would like to have diffrent md5sum.

```
$ ./sc.sh gcc -c "main.c" -o out
CMD gcc -c main.c -o out
MD5 b671a0f3b1235aa91e5f86011449c698

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Like here:

```
$ echo 'gcc -c "main.c" -o out' | md5sum - | cut -f1 -d" "
94d2bafbec690940d1b908678e9c9b7d
$ echo 'gcc -c main.c -o out' | md5sum - | cut -f1 -d" "
b671a0f3b1235aa91e5f86011449c698
```

Is such thing possible with bash? It would be awesome to not have it bound to any specific bash version, but if there is no other choice, then its also good.

Answer (score 0):

Inside script `gcc main.c` and `gcc "main.c"` are the same command.
`$0 = gcc` and `$1 = main.c` in both variants.

You cannot see the difference internally, and the script cannot make different signs, so you have no reason to see that.

Comment: I would like to have it inside my script, which is wrapper over compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Removing quotes when parsing the line that you have typed into the terminal is part of how the shell works. The commands you are typing are the same. Research how shell works and re-research a basic introduction to shell quoting.

> Like here:

Then pass it "like here". Clearly `'` quotes are missing from your commands, but they are present in the "like here" snippet.

```
$ ./sc.sh gcc -c main.c -o out
```

is exactly the same as

```
$ ./sc.sh gcc -c "main.c" -o out
```

is exactly the same as

```
$ ./sc.sh 'g''c''c' "-""c" 'main.c' '''''-o' 'ou't
```

and it happens to work the same way as the following, only because of your `IFS` and how you are using `="$@"`. Research what `$@` does and research `IFS`:

```
$ ./sc.sh 'gcc -c main.c -o out'
```

But the following command is different - the double quotes inside single quotes are preserved.

```
$ ./sc.sh 'gcc -c "main.c" -o out'
```

As a follow-up, research word splitting. Remember to check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net